# Writing the numbers as sum and products of units:is this an interesting result?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's call **elementary form** of a natural number $n$ a way of writing $n$ that as a string constituted by the following characters, that has mathematical meaning:

$$1 \ \ \ + \ \ \ \times \ \ \ ( \ \ \ )$$

It's forbiddent to put two $1$ next to each other and to multiply by $1$. For example:

$$7=1+1+(1+1+1)(1+1) \ \ \ 7=1+1+1+1+1+1+1 $$

Let's call $\varepsilon(x)$ the minimum number of ciphers $1$ needed to write $x$ in this form(for example $\varepsilon(3)=3$). I managed to prove that if a number is not prime then:

$$\varepsilon(p_1^{\alpha_1}....p_k^{\alpha_k})=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \alpha_i \varepsilon(p_i) $$

Basically the more efficient form is the factorization. Otherwise if $x$ is prime then the more efficient is in this form :

$$\varepsilon(p)=\pi_1+\pi_2$$

Where $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are $2$ isolated string-product. Moreover if the we call $[\pi_1]$ and $[\pi_2]$ the value that we obtain by interpreting mathematically these sub-strings we'll have that $[\pi_1]$ and $[\pi_2]$   can't be prime. For example if I want to find $\varepsilon(13)$, first I have to write it as sum of 2 composite numbers:

$$13=1+12$$
$$13=4+9$$

Then we write the addends as elementary form:

$$13=1+(1+1+1)(1+1)(1+1)$$
$$13=(1+1)(1+1)+(1+1+1)(1+1+1)$$

So we'll have $\varepsilon(13)=8$.
**I'm not saying that these are the unique ways in which you can obtain the minimum number of cipher $1$, I'm saying that these methods work always**

Is this interesting? I would really like to have your opinion.

:)

Comment: @WilliamElliot I gladly accept critiques but this is a bit vague

Comment: To be less harsh: This sort of thing is interesting to puzzlers - those whose interest is in exploring the implications of sets of artificial restrictions imposed "just because". And there are plenty of puzzlers out there. But to the more general mathematician, it doesn't offer much. The rules are not ones that are useful to restrict to. The implications are just not applicable to the problems we encounter. So, sorry, but for *most* of us, this has minor interest at best.